Python Kafka Test Container with SSL connection with broker fails and disconnects immediately after successful handshake
Container Setup:
kafka_container_ssl = KafkaContainer("confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest", port=9092)
@pytest.fixture
def _initiate_ssl_kafka_broker(monkeypatch_ssl_certificates):
    broker_cert_file, broker_cert_key_file, client_cert_file, client_ca_file, client_key_file = (
        monkeypatch_ssl_certificates
    )
    # Mount certificate directory to container
    kafka_container_ssl.with_volume_mapping(f"{broker_cert_file.parent.resolve()}", "/etc/kafka/certs")

    # kafka_container.with_env("KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE", "false")
    kafka_container_ssl.with_exposed_ports(9092)

    # Configure Kafka container for SSL
    kafka_container_ssl.with_env("KAFKA_SSL_KEYSTORE_TYPE", "PEM")
    kafka_container_ssl.with_env("KAFKA_SSL_KEYSTORE_LOCATION", "/etc/kafka/certs/broker_cert_key.pem")
    kafka_container_ssl.with_env("KAFKA_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_TYPE", "PEM")
    kafka_container_ssl.with_env("KAFKA_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION", "/etc/kafka/certs/client_ca.pem")
    kafka_container_ssl.with_env("KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP", "BROKER:SSL,PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT")
    kafka_container_ssl.with_env("KAFKA_LISTENERS", "PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9093, BROKER://0.0.0.0:9092")
    kafka_container_ssl.with_env("KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS", "PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9093, BROKER://0.0.0.0:9092")
    kafka_container_ssl.with_env("KAFKA_SSL_CLIENT_AUTH", "none")
    kafka_container_ssl.with_env("KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME", "BROKER")
    kafka_container_ssl.with_env("KAFKA_SSL_ENDPOINT_IDENTIFICATION_ALGORITHM", "")

    # Enable debug logging
    kafka_container_ssl.with_env("KAFKA_LOG4J_ROOT_LOGLEVEL", "DEBUG")

    # Start the Kafka container
    kafka_container_ssl.start()

    return kafka_container_ssl`


Broker Logs are attached
enter image description here
